# jquery adding element before data-category-id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code inside my construct:

```
<tr data-category-id="14" class="has-description no-logo">
```

I want to add a `<tr>` before that data-category-id="14". Can I archive that with jquery? I know I could add one before css selector, but those css selectors are allways the sames, so I need to get that data-category-id="14" to refer where to add the element before.

Comment: If you mean can you add an element before another element, yes you can. Please have a go, then come back if you run into problems.

Comment: your `category-id` always will be `14`  @Daniel ?

Comment: That data-category-id="14" inside tr tag has allways 14, yes, so before that I need to insert another tr element with jquery or somehow other, as I cannot modificate the code from the system itself which renders all the table stuff. And, I do NOT need to add it with on click, it should be added allways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can use [.before()](https://api.jquery.com/before/). Here is an example

```js
function on_click () {

  $('tr[data-category-id="14"]').before ('<tr><td>i was added</td></tr>');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr data-category-id="14" class="has-description no-logo">
    <td>i was already there</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="#" onclick="on_click ();">add element</a>
```

Comment: Not quite; the space between `tr` and `[d...` makes all the difference.

Comment: @Utkanos yes i edited my answer. i also was thinking about `before()` not `prepend()`. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Comment: Yes, a bit changed it is exactly what I was looking for. Thx a lot :)